# Uncontrolled multiple page reloading?

Tags: php

I notoced a strage behaviour at one of the websites I work on: trying to make an insert intro the database I saw that there were being inserted more than one(as I was expecting) row. After some attempts of indentifying the problem I made a test by creating a session variable (an array) in the index.php an pushed one value. At the first load of the page the session array printed one value, but on the next reloads it printed 6 values a time.

I mention that i had a .htaccess file, wich I suspected, but now it is empty, so it shouldn't be the problem.


Did anyone get this strange behavior? How can I fix it?


Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You can always have full control of any page reload.
Just keep an eye on the HTTP interchange while querying your server.
Use either Fiddler HTTP proxy or Firebug or any other addon with HTTP sniffer capability.
So, you will see every HTTP request your browser do as well as every HTTP response your server returns.

Comment: Thx a lot for the advice, Col. Shrapnel! I am not very familiar with this kind of debuging, although I use daily firebug like tools(the Chrom's one too) - but for other kind of tasks(most often - js debuging). The thing I don't understand is how can I see what determines my page to reaload multiple times, as long as in this tool I can see only the last request for the current URL. Judging by the multiple session array values pushed at one sigle refresh (as i mentioned in the question) I guess that the URL itself is being accessed multimple times - at least so it seems to me.

Comment: Well get yourself a tool that showing you all requests, not only last one. Not a big deal. Why to assume instead of being certain? LiveHTTPHeaders addon can show you the log, or Fiddler I mentioned above